# How can I give a shadow to the TouchableOpacity in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to apply shadow to TouchableOpacity in React native. I used both styled-components and inline style.
I have a View component called PaintCon and PainDummy and a TouchableOpacity component called PaintBtn.

I applied shadow to PaintBtn. But the strange thing is that the shadow works just fine, but PaintBtn shows a faint square box that I don't know. Use elevation to get this square. How do I get rid of this?
Below is my code.

[image]

```
    const PaintCon = styled.View`
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex:1;
    `;

    const PainDummy = styled.View`
    width: 20%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex:1;
    `;

    const PaintBtn = styled.TouchableOpacity`
    width: 80%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: lightcyan;
    border-radius: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    `;



    return (
    <PaintCon
    >
        <PainDummy
        >

        <PaintBtn 
        style={{backgroundColor:'#0097E8',
        shadowColor: '#52006A',
        shadowOffset: {width: 10, height: 3},
        shadowOpacity: 50,
        elevation: 10, 
    }}
        activeOpacity={0.7}>
        
        </PaintBtn>
        <Text>#0097E8</Text>
        </PainDummy>

        </PaintCon>

    )
```

Comment: can you add screen pic how it looks?

Comment: @azdeviz sorry i forgot i just added

Comment: hey @user19476497 can you share an expo link? will check there thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've given it a different background color (`lightCyan` in the PaintBtn styled component style). If you remove that background color, it should work?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use **TouchableOpacity** like that. Refer my example given below,

```js
 <TouchableOpacity style={styles.card}>
{{------My Codes-----}}
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

And the styles are,(For your reference I had set the ***ShadowColor*** to green),

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
    padding: 15,
    margin: 10,
    borderRadius: 15,
    shadowColor: "green",
    elevation: 15,
    flexDirection: "row",
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "space-between"
    }
```

[image: The below image is the example for the above button]